# Comparing a deterministic ODE versus its stochastic counterpart(Theory)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I have a question regarding the characterization of the differences between the deterministic ODE system versus its stochastic counterpart. For the sake of concreteness, suppose i have a deterministic  autonomous system. Let $x\in \mathbb{R^d}$
$$\dot{x(t)}=f(x)$$

Now lets us suppose that we introduce a little bit of noise in the system, and say that the stochastic counter part is 
$$dx(t)=f(x)dt+\sigma dW(t)$$ where $W(t)$ is d-dimensional independent Wiener processes. I am new to this subject and I would like to find some vocabulary to describe the difference in behavior of the two systems.

What i know till now: The second system can be solved by Euler-Muruyama discretization, and I could perhaps compare the trajectories for different values of $\sigma$. Also for some linear systems, we can expect to find the stationary distribution from the Fokker-Plank equation. (I have not found any results for nonlinear drift function) . Is there any other approach to studying the properties?

Comment: I mean, this is a bit like asking what's the difference between an ODE and a PDE. Can you be a bit more precise? If not, that's okay. Just letting you know it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: I suspected that. My problem is this: I have an ODE system which has a stable node. Simulating the stochastic 'counterpart', i observed that the long run values of the two variables are different in the stochastic case.  Are there any theoretical concepts that i can use to formalize this idea?  I hope this makes it slightly more clearer

Comment: " i observed that the long run values of the two variables are different in the stochastic case" I'm sorry, what does this mean?

Comment: The two variables, $x \in R^2$,in the stochastic case, seem to settle on a certain values. Even for very small value of the diffusion parameter, these "long -run" values are very different from the fixed point in the ODE.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not following. $x$ is your solution to the SDE and lives in $\Bbb R^2$? You're asking why $x$ settles on different things than the deterministic case?

Comment: I was wondering if there was something that quantifies how much the difference is between the this and the deterministic case. In the case the i could derive the stationary distribution, i was thinking i could study the hellinger distance as a function of the diffusion parameter. But i would have no idea how to go about it numerically.